# Error during post inflation process for TabHost

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-tabhost, android-framelayout

I have a FrameLayout inside of a TabHost. I am getting the following error. How can I get it to render in Eclipse?

```
Error during post inflation process:
The FrameLayout for the TabHost has no content. Rendering failed.
```

Here is my XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <!-- 
    <RelativeLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:id="@+id/actionbarRelativeLayout">
        <ImageButton android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/icon" android:id="@+id/stocktwitsImageButton"></ImageButton>
        <ImageButton android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/icon" android:id="@+id/composeImageButton" android:layout_alignParentRight="true"></ImageButton>
    </RelativeLayout>
-->

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="5dp">
        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:padding="5dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is extract from Android's source setupTabHost method:

```
final int count = content.getChildCount();

if (count == 0) {
    throw new PostInflateException(
            "The FrameLayout for the TabHost has no content. Rendering failed.\n");
}
```

As the exception says, you need to have content. Refactor the XML to:

```
<FrameLayout android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="5dp"> 
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/tab1"></LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Yep, you got it right, that's what's causing the error message. However I (and probably many others) fill this in during run-time; which adds more code as I have to remove this tab.  I guess that's progress.  Sigh.

Comment: Okay, the ghost tab doesn't show up (except in the graphical layout editor)! Cool--guess I should have waited until I tested it first before complaining.